# How to copy login/pass info from Google Chrome to Keepass?

Tags: google-chrome, keepass

What are the possible ways to copy your login/password data from Chrome to Keepass (2.14. if it matters) to an existing database (which probably already has some of those logins/passes).

*The second thing, btw, you can disregard; I can always copy them from one database to another, I guess.*

So, what would be the way to export from Chrome to Keepass?

Answer (score 5):

Use [ChromePass](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html) to extract your passwords.

> It is a portable application and does
>   not require any installation. Before
>   running ChromePass, close Google
>   Chrome and run it and wait for 1-2
>   minutes. It will display all the user
>   ids and passwords you have saved in
>   Google Chrome. These files can be
>   exported as txt and xml format.
>   However in order to import this to
>   KeePass select all the data in
>   ChromePass and paste it in "Open
>   Office" yes in "Open Office". The
>   reason is Microsoft® Excel® by default
>   does not enclose fields in quotes (").
>   It is recommended that you use
>   OpenOffice Calc to create a correct
>   CSV file or use the Generic CSV
>   Importer of KeePass 2.x (import your
>   CSV file into KeePass 2.x, then export
>   the data to a KeePass 1.x KDB file),
>   or fix the CSV file by manually adding
>   the quotes using a text editor.

Read more: http://www.techcorrespondent.com/2010/02/import-saved-password-of-google-chrome.html#ixzz1CAS3OhRO

Comment: Anyone else get a virus warning when downloading?

Comment: There's no source and no signature, /RUN ME IF YOU CAN/

Comment: It's open source : https://github.com/hassaanaliw/chromepass